# Neumann eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, eigenfunctions, laplacian

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Consider the  Neumann eigenvalue problem

$$ \Delta u =\lambda u \, \text{at} \, \Omega \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{\nu}}=0 \;\, \text{at} \;\, \partial\Omega \, $$

We say that $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of the above problem if there is  $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ (sobolev space and $u$ is nonzero) which satisfies the relation:

$$\int_{\Omega} \partial u \partial v dx= \lambda \int_{\Omega} uvdx\ \text{ for all }\ v\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$$

Show that the first eigenvalue is $0$ and the sequence of eigenvalues $\lambda_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

#### Context

I had this exercise in a test of university. In the first part I had to prove that the eigenvalues are positive. But this is easy, only take $v=u$ and use the definition. Show that the first eigenvalue is $0$ is the second part. I think I have to use bounded operators theorems. Any help?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: OP: you seem to have misunderstood the meaning of the votes to hold. We don't need your technical details to be more accurate, we need to know things more qualitative things. For example, where did you find this problem? Why do you care about the answer?

Comment: This is Theorem 8.10 in Salsa's book "PDEs in Action".